Is there a phrase/expression for "I'm already screwed, so I can't get more screwed"?
I'm wondering if there's an expression for the feeling where you are screwed, so you can do stuff that normally would be bad, since it's impossible to get "even more screwed".
Example context: suppose I rob a bank, killing several people along the way. If I'm caught, I'm screwed, so there's no reason for me not to carjack something for my getaway.

You've got nothing to lose.

used to say that you cannot make things worse, or cause any disadvantages for yourself by doing a particular thing - Cambridge


You could use this idiom: Might as well be hanged for a sheep as for a lamb.
Dictionary.com gives:

Might just as well be punished for a big misdeed as a small one. For example, I might as well be hanged for a sheep as a lamb and have a third piece of cake—I've gone off my diet anyhow .


Already a proverb in John Ray's 1678 collection, this expression alludes to the old punishment for stealing sheep, which was hanging no matter what the age or size of the animal.


"Might as well be hanged for a sheep as for a lamb." is doing something worse though where the punishment is the same. In the OP,  they already did the worst thing and they are going to commit a smaller offence after.

@ermanen The original offense included "killing several people", likely a life sentence or death penalty. The punishment can't get much worse.

@Barmar Yes, I'm saying the same thing.

'In for a penny, in for a pound' is not a close match – losing the extra investment (money, effort, time ...) need not leave one at rock bottom – but '[You] [m]ight as well be hanged for a sheep as [for] a lamb] is spot on. // Of course, there is self-deception involved if one believes in absolute righteousness, eternal judgement, and punitive measures after death.

@EdwinAshworth Yes, I think In for a penny, in for a pound doesn't quite match the requirement of the question.

Upvoted ... few seem to act on advice given.

They can only hang you once.
By Dashiell Hammett

In the specific context of murder: After the first, the rest are free.

When you've lost hope or have run out of possible solutions to a problem, you may feel a deep frustration and act out of desperation, considering  your decision as the way out of this hopeless situation.

Here are a few colloquial idioms that I frequently use:

Can't get any worse.

Example: Oh shoot, I incidentally killed several people while robbing a bank. Should I carjack something for my getaway? May as well, can't get any worse.


Go out with a bang.

Example: Oh fudge, I incidentally robbed a bank while killing several people. Should I lead the popo on a GTA-inspired police chase? Sure, may as well go out with a bang.


All in.

Example: I'm all in.





"Might as well be hanged for a sheep as for a lamb."

"Freedom's just another word for nothing left to lose"



You’ve hit bottom.
